# Text will not wrap to element when all anchors

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/awWmY/

For the life of me I can't solve this simple one. Why wont the text wrap to `#bigEnough`?

```
html{background:black;}

#bigEnough {
  width: 500px;
  text-wrap: normal;
}
#bigEnough a {
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  -ms-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
#tagCloud {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
  margin: -45px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I could find (with full cross-browser implementation) is to use `display: inline-block` on the `a` elements: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/awWmY/7/).

Note that I've also increased the width of the page, to show that the words will also occupy the same lines where space is available.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `word-break: break-word;` to your `#bigEnough` CSS will force the words to wrap but **not** at break points between the several `anchor` tags. I don't know if that's the behavior you were trying to achieve, but here's a demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awWmY/5/).

Hope that helped in any manner!

Answer (score 0):

Because word wrapping depends on there being a space between words.

Answer (score 0):

The others are right, you need to use spaces for words to wrap. If you want to avoid doing that, however, I've had success with:

- [Hyphenator](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/)

Hyphenator is a JavaScript solution that automatically wraps long words so that they fit in their parent container and inserts hyphens where the wrap occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you should really have some whitespace between the `a` elements. But if you cannot change the markup, you can inject no-break spaces U+200B (which are line-breaking opportunities) with generated content:

```
#bigEnough a:after { content: "\200B"; }
```

Usual CSS Caveats apply.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure sure what you are trying to achieve but you can try this if this is what you need

```
#bigEnough a {
    display:inline-block;
    /* rest of your styles*/  
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/awWmY/8/).